# Populate data that does not match between two lists based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to know if I am able to populate "spill" when two lists don't match based on multiple criteria with a single formula. I have a master employee listing and then a list of 10 required trainings they must be enrolled in. I have an enrollment list that shows every employee and the course. A single employee should show up 10 times on that list. Once for each course. I would like to write a single formula that will autopopulate the names and course of the people from the master employee list who do not show enrolled and what course/courses they are not showing enrolled in. It may be multiple courses for the same employee. I have written filter formulas that work by creating a column for each course beside the master employee listing and then identifying them by returning a false of "not enrolled". Great for me, viewing everyone but I'd like to just create a compiled list of the employees name and course they're not enrolled in automatically in a single table

Currently using this formula in each "courses" column. Of course the course is different in each formula for each column

`=filter(Table3[status],(table3[emp num]=Sheet1!D3)*(table3[course]="HAZCOM TRNG"),"NOT ENROLLED")`

This works but I want a more efficient way to just see a single list of the non enrolled by course they're not enrolled in

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some sample data (best by using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation). Then it is much easier to help you. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.